# How to increase BTREE index creation speed

Tags: postgresql, performance, amazon-rds, database-performance, database-indexes

I have an RDS snapshot of a database that has a 1 TB table. I am trying to create an index on one of the columns. Since this is a clone table (for testing purposes) I decided to use an m6g.large which has 2 VCPUs, 8 GB ram, 16000 IOPS

The index creation has taken more than 2 hours which is not the problem, but the CPU utilization is less than 10% and the IOPS has not hit 300.

What can I do next to increase the speed of the index creation, I am considering increasing instance size which might give me more memory at hand. Is there something I am missing?

I have tried a few parameter changes

- work_mem 16 MB
- shared_buffers 4GB
- max_parallel_workers 8

with all of that, the index creation still takes more than 2 hours

- maintenance_work_mem 2GB
  Here the one difference that I saw was memory dropped from 4.7 GB to 2.7 GB and remained constant. No spike in CPU utilization or IOPS. But index creation is still in progress

Note

- this is a test database and has no other queries running.

Comment: IOPS is for short reads.  There are also IO throughput limits.  For large reads and writes like you are likely to get with index creation, you will hit a throughput limit long before the IOPS limit, so that could be the limit you are hitting.

Comment: so the max storage throughput set is 500 MiBps. It barely touched 20 MiBps.

Comment: Log on with another session, and look at the wait_event field of pg_stat_avtivity for the session doing the indexing (and any parallel workers it has).  You will have to sample this many times to get the consensus value.  If the consensus is NULL, then i don't know what more you can do.  I guess contact AWS RDS support, or replicate the data out of RDS where you can investigate using things like `perf`.